# vue.js confitionally import mixin

Tags: vue.js, mixins, vue-mixin

i've been working on mixins but i can't have any clue with this.

what i want is conditionally import js file but NOT using component.

this is the FIRST way what i've been doing so far.

```
export default {
    mixins:[],
    mounted(){     
      if( condition1){
         require('../folder/file1.js');
      }else if(condition2){
         require('../folder/file2.js');
      }else if(condition3){
         require('../folder/file3.js');
      }
    }
}
```

but the problem is that i don't know how to make these js files as mixins !
is there any way to make this as a mixins?

---

this is the SECOND way

normally mixins are declared like this, so i imported upper than this.
like below

```
if(condition1) {
  import file1 from '../folder/file1.js'
}else if(condition2){
  import file2 from '../folder/file2.js'
}
export default {
  mixins: [file1, file2]
}
```

but it keeps make error so it just keeps making blank page.
(error msg is like something undefined with conditions..!)
so will it be solved if i made condition right? or do i missing something?

your help will be very very appriciated :-) thanks!

Comment: Unless the mixin files are very large, you might consider either importing them all, and then adding logic to your component to pick the mixin variables or functions you need.  Or possibly combine the multiple mixin files into one mixin for import.  And make sure your mixin file(s) are formatted correctly (see docs) if you haven't already.

Comment: ok maybe i should do what you told. thanks!